# No graphics after update from CE1.7 to CE1.9

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to update our web site to 1.9. I created a new fresh install on a new host, copied all the necessary files and the database. When I try to connect to the new site I see only text on white background. No colors, no graphics, just text and links.

What did I do wrong?

problem solved. I forgot to add a "/" at the end of the path on core_donfig_data

Comment: check the browser console and see if and what type of errors you have

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the package settings are incorrect. If you look at the rendered source, you will likely see references such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://site.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
                                 That should be "rwd", not "base"-----------^
```